# Switching between multiple layouts in one LinearLayout dynamically

Tags: android, layout, include

I have a spinner and a LinearLayout in my application. When the item in the spinner is changed, the LinearLayout is supposed to contain a different layout (a different xml file which is a LinearLayout, too). I´ve tried using View.inflate method but the layout never changed from the first one. What should I do to solve this problem?

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            changeForm(id);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            ;
        }
    });

}

private void changeForm(long id) {
    LinearLayout formLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.type_layout);
    if(id==0){View.inflate(this, R.layout.text, formLayout);}
    else if(id==3){View.inflate(this, R.layout.phonecall, formLayout);}     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put all of your LinearLayouts in a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), then just change the visibility on them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this would be to use the android ViewFlipper. That allows you to add mulitple child under it. And the viewflipper will only show 1 child at a time using a line like

```
viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

It also allows for in and out animations while switching between views.

These are tutorials for it

[Tutorial 1](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=android+viewflipper+example&pbx=1&oq=android+viewf&aq=1&aqi=g4&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=0l0l1l88l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1769acd9df1e7faf&biw=1920&bih=930), [Tutorial 2](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example)